# Calling New activity after video completes

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-intent, android-videoview

I am trying to implement an onCompletionListener so that when the splash video completes, the tab Activity ( where all the content is contained) is called. The problem is, after the video plays, the next activity is not called. Here's the code:

```
package com.companyname.cpny;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class splash extends Activity 

     {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
VideoView vs = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.imlsplash);
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName() + "/"+R.raw.iphonesplashfinal);
vs.setVideoURI(uri);
vs.start();     
vs.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent main = new Intent(splash.this, tabhost.class);
                splash.this.startActivity(main);
                splash.this.finish();
    }

});
}
}
```

Comment: Have you verified that onCompletion is called? You might need to se the onCompletionListener before calling start().

Comment: How can I verify that? Everything in the error log looks as if everything is called properly until the Public void section. I know that everything above the line vs.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() { is working fine because I have implemented the onCompletionListener above it and the video doesn't play.

Comment: Set a break point in your onCompletionListener...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this

```
 vs.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

             splash.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Intent main = new Intent(splash.this, tabhost.class);
                        splash.this.startActivity(main);
                        splash.this.finish();
                    }
                });
    }
```

EDIT:
Can you also register the listener first and call start later.

```
 vs.start()
```

Comment: Activities don't need to be started on the UI thread - so this probably won't fix it.

Comment: @Berdon: You are probably right, however as a thumb rule I desist doing anything to do with main activity in listeners.

Comment: Yeah that didn't work. Could this be an issue? The splash activity is a completely different class outside of my tabhost activity (obviously). for instance, the tabhost activity does not start the splash activity; actually vice versa. do I need to overlay the splash activity onto my tab activity so that I can finish(); the splash and the tabhost just be there? Does that make sense?

Comment: No that is not required, the key question is does you onCompletion() method is getting called? Can you put a break point there to check if it is indeed getting called.

Comment: I am not sure where to put the break point. This is my first app that I have implemented this kind of Listener. Could you tell me before which line?

Comment: Add it on the first line of code inside your onCompletion method. Additionally did you try calling vs.start() after you register your listener?

Comment: Give me a moment, it is not allowing a break; command inside the method... >:/

Comment: Ok, I do not think I have my method properly defined. Any suggestions?

Comment: PRoblem Resolved. All is well. I just overlooked something in my manifest file. Thanks for your help all

Comment: @Derok8 How did you resolve the problem? What did you overlook?